# Single board computer or system on module under 100$ that can handle 4k HDMI in + out

Tags: hdmi

I'm looking for a single board computer or system on module that can handle simultaneous 4k HDMI input and output (optimally at 60hz).

Comment: Do you have requirements for a chipset that is capable of *processing* an HD video input? Or is it just meant to be a pass-through?